# Trying to handle a 500 error returned from the RestTemplate used inside an Http.outboundGateway in Spring-Integration DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to catch the Exceptions thrown from the RestTemplate (500 error) when used with a Http.OutboundGateway and send to a failure Channel or success channel. I have tried all sorts before coming back to stackoverflow to ask for help (tried to route by payload, errorhandlers) but i just can't seem to get this to work in a integration test. The success or failure should send message to a channels and then the net flow with use a JdbcMessageHandler and updates the DB accordingly.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(updateSuccessChannel)
                .log(message -> message)
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway(updateTicketURI, restTemplate)
                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT), out -> out.advice(expressionAdvice()))
                .get();


public Advice expressionAdvice() {
        final ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
        advice.setFailureChannel(failureChannel);
        advice.setSuccessChannel(successChannel);
        advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("#exception");
        advice.setTrapException(true);
        return advice;
    }
```

I am using Wiremock to return the status code in the unit test and am mocking the JdbcMessageHandler so i can see the interactions with them.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to handle the failures thrown from a restTemplate, I have tried implementing a response error handler for the reset template but I don't see how I can get the original message when back in the work flow.

Any help gratefully received this seems to be a re-occurring pattern and I just can't seem to get this to work :(

Comment: You're not describing a problem "can't get this work" doesn't explain your problem. The payload of the message sent to the `failureChannel` is a `MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException` with the `failedMessage` property, cause and expression evaluation result (which in your case is the cause again).

Comment: Sorry for the "can't get this to work". Apologies for lack of problem . When I raise 500 error from wiremock. i do no see any messages passed to the error, failure  or success channels

Comment: Run it in a debugger and step through the `doInvoke()` method to see what's happening.